# How large can an H2 database be?

Tags: database, clojure, jvm, h2

How large can an H2 database be? I have been using an H2 database with a web application I wrote in Clojure for about half a year, and the database is getting quite large: The current size of the .h2.db file is 143GB with one table containing over 330000 images. The application is fairly stable with occasional pauses caused by the JVM garbage collector and database errors such as "Missing lob entry."  The current memory footprint is around 6GB, which is acceptable, and I was able to recover from these database errors so far by reconstructing the database. I do wonder, however, how long I can practically keep this setup before migrating to a multi-threaded database engine such as PostgreSQL and MySQL, and I would love to hear from those of you who have experiences working with large H2 databases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would like to report, for future reference, that I ended up having major performance and stability issues with H2 and switched to HyperSQL (http://hsqldb.org/). For my web application, HyperSQL is much more stable and actually faster than H2. HyperSQL's support for multi-threading was particularly important, and I haven't had corrupt databases with HyperSQL like I did with H2. I also made my application database-agnostic and compatible with MySQL and PostgreSQL, both of which seem more stable and responsive with my application than H2. I am aware that H2 was not designed for such a huge database as mine, but I thought I should let other readers know some of the consequences of running a huge H2 database.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, these are the limits:
http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations

However, the real world limits are going to depend on your application. If you can only tolerate 5ms latency for example, a 4TB database with no indices probably won't cut it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am aware of these limits, and my sense is that I would face practical limits much sooner than theoretical limits. I am talking about a web application here, so 500ms latency is acceptable even though it is not ideal. Also, my database is appropriately indexed.

Comment: I guess my point was we can't really give you your limits unfortunately. If you were looking for people to tell you they have done it you will probably get some, but it won't be accurate for you. For example, I have ran applications with DBs in the 500-1000GB range that still performed rather well, mostly SQL, but some MongoDB or in-memory (with file backing) ones as well.

Comment: Are any of these "DBs in the 500-1000GB range" H2 databases? I would love to hear about real-world large H2 databases even if they don't quite match with my own setup.

Comment: I meant to put that in my previous comment. Unfortunately no, I've never used H2 anywhere near that large. You're several orders of magnitude larger than any H2 DB I've ever used, even for testing.